# Выравнивание и abi

Tags: c++, c, struct, alignment

У меня есть пара вопросов, которые касаются выравнивания полей простых структур (pod) и правильной портируемой реализации интерфейсов, в которых такие структуры используются (стандартизация и стабильность abi).

1. Дают ли стандарты C и C++ гарантии, что разметка следующего типа везде и всегда будет одинакова?

   struct Type
   {
   char a;
   uint32_t b;
   };
2. Каков самый правильный способ выразить портируемый и стабильный формат типа языковыми средствами? Предположим, что порядок байтов нас не интересует, а размеры полей в составном типе гарантированно известны. Многие просто используют упакованные структуры, но я бы такой вариант портируемым и безопасным не назвал.

Comment: ни какого «abi», а уж тем более его «стабильности» c т/з стандарта нет... и что именно ты имеешь в виду под «портируемый и стабильный формат типа»?

Comment: Обычно используют #ifdef ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет, стандарт разрешает любые дополнительные оступы в структуре (но не перед первым элементом). Но на практике ничего такого быть не должно. Также стандарт не требует выравнивания uint32_t по 4 байтам.
2. Упакованные структуры. Даже у GCC и MSVC синтакис для них почти одинаковый, так что довольно портируемо на мой вкус.

   Если не нравится, то можно вместо этого можно для спокойствия заполнить весь padding в структуре неиспользуемыми переменными (или безымянными битовыми полями).

Comment: Тем не менее стандарт гарантирует выравнивание всей структуры по размеру максимального элемента в неё входящего. ABI (архитектурный) указывает требования  padding & alignment. (@Fat-Zer FYI)